# Single Guillemets in LaTeX

Tags: csquotes, quotation

I am looking for a way to enquote using **single** (›ABC‹), not double (»ABC«) Guillemets. I am currently using the csquotes package but can't figure it out since I'm still new to LaTeX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sticking with `csquotes`, and imagining here that you are writing German, you might go with

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{german}
  {\guilsinglright}
  {\guilsinglleft}
  [0.025em]
  {\guillemotright}
  {\guillemotleft}
\begin{document}

\enquote{ABC}

\end{document}
```

Here, I've swapped the 'outer' and 'inner' quite signs from the standard
`guillemets` substyle for German.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

›ABC‹

\end{document}
```

You can also use `\guilsinglright` and `\guilsinglleft`